# Running .jar file is working, but .exe file is showing error "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8 (64-bit)"

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to run [winthing](https://github.com/msiedlarek/winthing) software on the windows 10 computer.

It is working fine when I run .jar from .bat file (in the .bat file I have something like `java -Dbroker="..." ... -jar winthing-1.4.2.jar`)

But when I double click on winthing-1.4.2.exe file I just get an error:

```
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8 (64-bit)
```

I'm pretty sure that I have JRE installed on my computer (running .jar file works fine), but still .exe file does not work with this error message.

I think that this is just a misconfiguration with my windows 10 computer. Maybe you can tell me what should I do with windows to make .exe file work?

Comment: Some ways to analyse it further: Do you have java in the %PATH%? Do you have correctly set JAVA_HOME env variable? Do you have at least `java -version` >= 1.8? And the java version is x64?

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/osg9sAs6I2iqcWILvpNrcuphr34.png